# Choosing Between Different Repositories Serving The Same Package

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, repository

(Kind of a noob here) I always assumed that when there are two repositories serving package, and when I wanted to install it, apt will choose the one which has the latest version. This is because, when I wanted to install Lollypop with the default repos list, it would bring up an older version, and after I added the developer's PPA, it would install from the PPA which is the latest.

I went the same route with spotify: Added spotify's repo as [directed](https://www.spotify.com/in/download/linux/), and went ahead with the installation. But it downloaded the package from Pop!_OS' proprietary repository.

One of the lines in the apt install output:

```
Get:2 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary focal/main amd64 spotify-client amd64 1:1.1.10.546.ge08ef575-19 [115 MB]
```

It's prioritizing Pop's repo over spotify's. After searching, I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/124174/how-can-i-specify-the-repository-from-which-a-package-will-be-installed-emacs). I can specify the repository with "-t" option. So I compared the syntax and the repo details, and decided to put "stable" in place of "squeeze-backports" (Spotify's repo URI is http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free). But it still installed from Pop's repo and got the output same as the above. I also tried putting "non-free" as the argument. It threw an error.

Am I doing anything wrong? (Maybe I put in the wrong argument?)

Or how do I set my manager to prioritize one repo over another?

I also tried something called [apt pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto). The guide only details the things for system packages. The identifiers for the URIs were "hardy", "intrepid", etc. I can't find anything other than "stable" in place of "hardy" in my case, and "stable" could mean other repos as well. This is what I added to the file in preference.d directory:

```
Package: spotify-client
Pin: release n=stable
Pin-Priority: 1002
```

I tried anyway with what I got and it didn't work. Is there any way I can specify the actual URI explicitly when I install the package?

Now I just installed the damn thing by wget-ing the .deb file from [here](http://repository.spotify.com/pool/non-free/s/spotify-client/). It was hard to find the exact URL to download the file.

Please answer the above questions. It could help me in the future for other packages. Or ultimately I could learn something.

Comment: If you're using PopOS, you should probably ask in https://unix.stackexchange.com/ and not https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: That being said, there is a comprehensive guide to pinning here - https://wiki.debian.org/AptConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is spotify's side. After digging deeper, I found that they updated the [package files' directory](https://repository-origin.spotify.com/pool/non-free/s/spotify-client/) with the new version, but haven't updated the [package details file](https://repository-origin.spotify.com/dists/stable/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages). It still reads `Version: 1:1.1.10.546.ge08ef575-19` and `Filename: pool/non-free/s/spotify-client/spotify-client_1.1.10.546.ge08ef575-19_amd64.deb` (older version) under `spotify-client`. So it must have downloaded from the other repo since they are the same version. But I still can't understand why it downloaded from the Pop's repo even after setting the priority to spotify's repo.

(Correct me if I'm wrong)